# Postcss - color function plugin - "Unable to parse color from string"

Tags: css, webpack, webpack-style-loader, postcss, cssnext

Using the following postcss plugins:

- postcss-cssnext
- postcss-nested
- postcss-color-function

I constantly hit the following error, when using the following color function.

`Unable to parse color from string "l(-20%)"`

### styles.css

```
@import 'variables.css';
//          ^-- contains: --blue: #3892e0;

& a {
    color: color(var(--blue), l(-20%));
    &:hover {
        color: color(var(--blue), l(0%));
    }
}
```

### Webpack 2 snippet

```
{
    loader: 'postcss-loader',
    options: {
        plugins: [
            cssImport({ path: './src' }),
            cssnext({ browsers: ['last 2 versions'] }),
            colorFunction(),
            nested(),
        ],
    }
}
```

Comment: colorFunction is already included in cssnext. And cssnext also already include a draft nesting proposal syntax.

Comment: Gotcha - to clarify - I can drop `nested()` and `colorFunction()` from the plugin lineup? It doesn't really impact the question/answer in this particular case, as the error message is still quite cryptic. Btw, nice work on CSSNext @MoOx

Comment: Obviously it's not an anwser, just a comment. Check out what is included http://cssnext.io

Comment: Groovy thanks @MoOx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error, although not descriptive, is indicating that the `,` is unneeded. This follows future CSS (proposed) spec, but can be a nasty habit to drop if you come from *any* other language.

The solution is simply to remove the `,`'s:

```
& a {
    color: color(var(--blue) l(-20%));
    &:hover {
        color: color(var(--blue) l(0%));
    }
}
```